# verbose_name_plural not working properly in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, metaclass

I am trying to change display for Model name in my django admin using **verbose_name_plural** in class Meta.

here is my code :

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Country"
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
```

But it is not working, the display name is not changed in django admin list.

[django-admin list models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQGNI.png)

I also tried to :

- place the "Meta" class in admin.py -> not working
- already makemigrations & migrate -> still same result
- stop and start server

Thank you for any comment/advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly happen,
but I am using PyCharm as my editor,
After I closed my PyCharm, reopen the project and re-run the server,
It is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Country"
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name
```